# Syntax works on MySQL but doesn't works on MYSQL DB Connector (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

this is my very first question, sorry if it's a bit messy, I executed this Query on MYSQL

```
INSERT INTO ms_print_stock (product_code, product_name, product_stock, product_unit) SELECT * FROM ms_product WHERE product_code = %s
```

but it doesn't work on MYSQL DB Connector. However, if I changed `%s` to a value it works. it returns this error.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

by the way here's the full code on python

```
self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
self.sql_print = "INSERT INTO ms_print_stock (product_code, product_name, product_stock, product_unit) SELECT * FROM ms_product WHERE product_code = %s"
print(self.sql_print)
self.val_print = (self.txtPCode.text())
self.mycursor.execute(self.sql_print, self.val_print)
print("BERHASIL")
self.mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Hi Clarissa, please see here for instructions on how to format the code in your question better: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Try `self.val_print = (self.txtPCode.text(),)` (note the extra comma)

Comment: this works perfectly fine! thanks! i was wondering what did the extra comma do though?

Answer (score 0):

be sure your select  match the number and type of columns in insert

```
    "INSERT INTO ms_print_stock (product_code, product_name, product_stock, product_unit) 
        SELECT col_x_product_code
            , col_x_product_name
            , col_x_product_stock
            , col_x_product_unit
         FROM ms_product WHERE product_code = %s"
```

Comment: are you sure you have a valid value for  %s content  self.val_print  ..
 (self.txtPCode.text())

Comment: yes, i tried printing it, it returns the value of the product_code. the weirdest thing is, i tried querying using the same value and conditions, it works in other queries but not this specific one.

Comment: which is the value of product code  .. ?? show me  the exact sample

Comment: self.sql = "UPDATE ms_product SET product_stock = product_stock + (SELECT (quantity_in - quantity_out) AS total FROM `surat_jalan` WHERE nomorsj = %s AND product_code = %s) WHERE product_code = %s" this works perfectly fine

Comment: is not the same query  .. so  show me (if you can) a clear sample if the product_code you are using and raise the error